# Crash in boost exception code while building ec string

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to figure out a crash dump that I got when initiating a boost implementation of unix domain socket.

What's strange about it is that the relevant frame is when it parsed the `ec.what()` which is a function that basically create a string message ...

```
Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   P 0x104919660 boost::system::error_code::what() const (in P_arm64.dsym) + 528 + 251488
1   P 0x104919654 boost::system::error_code::what() const (in P_arm64.dsym) + 516 + 251476
2   P 0x104918ea8 boost::system::system_error::system_error(boost::system::error_code const&, char const*) (in P_arm64.dsym) + 308 + 249512
3   P 0x104adbd10 boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol, boost::asio::any_io_exec
utor>::connect(boost::asio::local::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol> const&) (in P_arm64.dsym) + 1808 + 2096400
(--> this is my c'tor that initiate the unix domain socket) 
4   P 0x104ad9ed4 service::api::Instance(std::__1::function<void (std::__1::
```

Besides the callstack, I could generate a crash file with a crash reason

```
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 10 Bus error: 10
Terminating Process:   exc handler [2253]

VM Region Info: 0x107008fa8 is in 0x107006000-0x10705e000;  bytes after start: 12200  bytes before end: 348247
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      __TEXT                      10664e000-107006000    [ 9952K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...s/MacOS/P
--->  __DATA_CONST                107006000-10705e000    [  352K] r--/rw- SM=COW  ...s/MacOS/P
      __DATA                      10705e000-107072000    [   80K] rw-/rw- SM=COW  ...s/MacOS/P
```

So It seems like when the ec message is created, we attempt to write a read only memory (DATA_CONST) . I think that this is the problematic code :

```
source_location const & location() const BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
   BOOST_STATIC_CONSTEXPR source_location loc;
   return lc_flags_ >= 4? *reinterpret_cast<source_location const*>( lc_flags_ &~ static_cast<boost::uintptr_t>( 1 ) ): loc;
}
```

which is called from here

```
std::string what() const
{
    std::string r = message();
    r += " [";
    r += to_string();
    if( has_location() )
    {
        r += " at ";
-->     r += location().to_string();
    }

    r += "]";
    return r;
}
```

However, i don't understand where do we attempt to write to the const expression 'loc'... any idea what may be the reason ?

Comment: This might be an excellent question for https://github.com/boostorg/exception/issues. I expect @pdimov to know where to look/what question to ask. If you have a minimal reproducer, be sure to include it.

Comment: Hi @sehe, thanks for your guidance. I've files a ticket in boostorg/exception and added some additional information. here the link : https://github.com/boostorg/exception/issues/48